# Javascript method hangs before properly executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I apologize in advance for the long question.

I am currently working on editing filelocker2 source code. It is a file sharing app. What I want to do is ensure that after a user is created, the first time they log on they should change their password. In terms of how the app works what is common to every first logon is the signing of the Terms of Service. `

```
if(document.referrer == "$fl.rootURL/sign_tos")

{

    if (window.confirm('In order to proceed you are required to change your password'))

    {

    location.href = 'javascript:dismissStatusMessage();javascript:loadEditAccount()'

    }

    else

    {

    document.location.href = '$fl.rootURL/logout'

    }   

}
```

`

I placed this code in script tags after the body tag in the footer.tmpl file so the page could load fully before executing the method, however nothing happens.

The web app continues without loading anything.

At this point if I use the web development tools and run the debugger it gets to the normal page without loading the edit account box. The difference is now, that the page freezes and the debugger executes to completion. If I press pause then play it proceeds to execute the code and load the dialog. this is the method that should be executing but doesnt.

```
function loadEditAccount()
{

    $("#userPassword").val("");

    $("#userPasswordConfirm").val("");

    getCLIKeyList();

    $("#editAccountBox").dialog("open");
}
```

If I get my reputation up and can add images I will aim to better explain my problem.

For the most part my question would be, how, without using the developer tools do I push the page to go through and execute the function.

Ps: This is a task I was given after having done a 6 month Java course. I have no History whatsoever with web based languages.

Comment: To cause navigation, set `location.href` (or `window.location.href`), not `document.location.href` (re your `document.location.href = '$fl.rootURL/logout'` line).

Comment: It's not the problem (I'm pretty sure), but rather than using `location.href` to execute arbitrary JavaScript from within JavaScript code, just call the functions you want to call directly. So don't use `location.href = 'javascript:dismissStatusMessage();javascript:loadEditAccount()'`, just use `dismissStatusMessage(); loadEditAccount();`

Comment: After further inspection its not that it hangs its that I set a breakpoint at the loadEditAccount so it proceeds there. I get this error.                                                          Error loading source:
loadSourceError

Comment: That means my second answer wasn't it (I've deleted it). So the obvious question is: What happens when you step through the function in the debugger? It's all very straightforward other than that I have no idea what your `getCLIKeyList` function does.

Comment: When I step through it executes without problem and then opens the dialog box. I suspect however that it only reaches the loadEditAccount method because of the breakpoint. Other than that it just doesnt seem to reach it.

Comment: *"I suspect however that it only reaches the loadEditAccount method because of the breakpoint"* That isn't likely at all.

Comment: Is it possible that since signing the tos takes you to the main page that the alert happens before the page is fully loaded and the method is unable to see the #editAccountBox @T.J. Crowder

Comment: Not if it's after those elements in the markup, which it would seem to be from your question (*"I placed this code in script tags after the body tag in the footer.tmpl file..."*). This concept of the page being "fully loaded" is largely a very common misconception; all that's required for code to see an element is for the code to be run after the element exists. You could have `<div id="foo">...</div>` **immediately** followed by `<script>document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "This is foo";</script>` and it would work. (I'm not recommending it, end of the `body` is good.)

Answer (score 0):

By doing the following.

`var editBox = $("#editAccountBox")
editBox.dialog("open");`

It works.